# Javascript works only in debug mode

Tags: javascript

I am conditionally loading JavaScript and it seems like it doesn't run when I run it normally. But when I run the same with debug mode with breakpoint. It works fine. Could anyone please let me know what is the issue?

I have this JavaScript in header of the html.

```
<script>
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.type = 'text/javascript';
if(server == "a"){
    sc.src = "sample.js";
}
else{
    sr.src = "test.js";
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
sample.getSomething();
</script>
```

This sample object is an object in sample.js/test.js and gets loaded only in debug mode, otherwise it is `'not available'`

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Have you tried putting in `alert()` calls to ensure the script is running?

Comment: Typo here? `sr.src`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried to put `console.log(stmt)` and it prints the stmt. When I said it doesn't work, I mean I feel script is not being loaded to head.

Comment: Do you get this error in all browsers or only in 1 or 2 like IE?

Comment: @AnkeKnicker I tested on forefox and chrome it is consistent. I feel there is some timing issue. I have a script after the above script element which makes a function call on the object from the above script. It works if I run in debug mode or put some `alert("test")` in the above script. But if there is no break point/ no alert statement the function calls are not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors in developer console

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not seeing any errors, and I have edited my code above please see if that helps.

Comment: How do you set `server`?

Comment: I suspect this is related to an asynchronous function that you haven't shown. When you stop at the breakpoint, that allows the async function to complete and set the variable.

Comment: server is undefined, so only test.js will ever load (given the code shown). sample will have to be defined in both test.js and sample.js.  In "not available" an error you are seeing, or your description of the problem?

Comment: @Barmar `server` is set using url parameters, it is being set appropriately. I tried to put `console.log(stmt)` inside my script and it always print the stmt to the console.

Comment: What is `stmt` and what does it have to do with the above code?

Comment: @Barmar I have just added some logging statements to the above code, that is what I am trying to tell.                                                                          I added logging statements and it prints those statements to the console.

Comment: As @isherwood asked before: Is `sr.src` a typo for `sc.src`? Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: The problem is that the script is loaded asynchronously. See the duplicate question for how to deal with this.